# mongoose: mongodb update with multi true not updating all the documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

mongodb update with multi true not updating all the documents, rather it just updates the initial 1 or 2 documents. Here is the query. Is it because of the limit I am using ? Anyway, I removed the limit and it is still not updating all 31 documents found by the matching criteria. Is there anything wrong with the mongoose update syntax?

```
db.update({biztype:msg.biztype, 'g_location': {$near: [msg.lng, msg.lat], $maxDistance:10/111.12}},{
                        $push:{fromusers:{
                            ip: ip,
                            msg: msg.msg,
                            u_name: msg.name,
                            u_mobile: msg.mobile,
                            u_email: msg.email,
                            comment_date: new Date()
                        }}
                    }, false, true).
                    limit(10);
```

Comment: Do you mean that when you run the query with that filter you get back 31 documents?  Which ones are the ones being updated?

Comment: This appears to be in the shell and not using Mongoose?  Is `db.update` a typo (missing a collection name)?

Comment: @Asya, first 2 doc are being updated. At times only the first one is being updated.

Comment: @JohnnyHK, Before posting this to SO, I changed the model name to db. Actually this is a code taken from my node.js app. Well, instead of db. you can change this to someModel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the understanding that `db` is a Mongoose model, you need to modify your parameter list to be compatible with the [Mongoose update](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update):

```
db.update({biztype:msg.biztype, 'g_location': {$near: [msg.lng, msg.lat], $maxDistance:10/111.12}},
    {
        $push:{fromusers:{
            ip: ip,
            msg: msg.msg,
            u_name: msg.name,
            u_mobile: msg.mobile,
            u_email: msg.email,
            comment_date: new Date()
        }}
    },
    { multi: true }, // <== This boolean option goes into the options parameter
    function (err, numberAffected) {
        // Your callback, if needed
    }
);
```

Comment: This is great. I did not know about it. will try it soon.

Comment: in case i want upsert to be true and multi false, i hope it would be  { multi: false , upsert: true }

Comment: Thanks @JohnnyHK, also worked for me, but the mongoose documentation is weird, doesn't mention nothing about multi, at least I didn't find it.

Comment: @Ito `multi` is listed in the `Valid options:` section of the docs for [`Model.update`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update).